# How to display the previous map zoom level after finishing the current map in android

Tags: android

I have two maps that are displaying one after the other. Let the activites be Map1 and Map2. First I am displaying the Map1 and then going to Map2 from Map1. Whenever I click on the back button on Map2 I am finishing the Map2 and going to the Map1.

But here the issue is the Map1 is getting the same zoom level as Map2. In the Map1 I am displaying a Marker for the specified address and in the Map2 I am displaying the current location. Both are different MapViews. Can anyone tell me how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

When you start the second map activity, save the zoom level as an extra in the intent. Then load it in the second map activity and set the zoom level accordingly.

Saving in the first map activity:

```
Intent map2Intent = new Intent(this, Map2Activity.class);
map2Intent.putExtra("zoomLevel", mapView.getZoomLevel());
startActivity(map2Intent);
```

Loading in the second:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    int zoom = extras.getInt("zoomLevel");
    mapView.setZoomLevel(zoom);
}
```

EDIT:

After re-reading your question, I realize I misunderstood. To get the same zoom level in Map 1 after returning from Map 2, you could save the value in SharedPreferences, like this

```
    SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putInt("zoomLevel", mapView.getZoomLevel());
    editor.commit();
```

then start the activity with `startActivityForResult(Intent, REQUEST_CODE` where `REQUEST_CODE` is an integer you use later to identify where you are coming back from. Now implement the onActivityResult method:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case CHANGE_BUILDING:

        SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(0);
        mapView.setZoomLevel(settings.getInt("zoomLevel", 0));
    }
}
```